# Skipping tests that require certain features for target

Tags: pytest

I have a ton of features that are spread over many variants of the target I am testing. I would like to skip specific tests if the variant does not support this feature.
I have considered `@pytest.mark.skipif` but that means I will end up having a very long like checking the specific scenarios.
I got a dict containing my targets configurations and I plan on pulling the information out of that dict. The dict is available after `pytest_configure` hook has been called.

I have also considered adding a custom marker and then within the `pytest_runtest_setup` hook skip test if the marker is set for the testcase and the variant does not support this feature.

The dict with information is constant per-test and contains strings and ints for each target being tested. In most cases the important information is common across all targets.

I assume I will have to compare in different ways. `in, not in, ==, !=` in order to skip all the correct tests.
I also would like to skip them and not just deselect the tests as it gives me an obvious indication if a test is not supported for the variant.

I would like to hear if there are any other interesting ways of doing this.

Comment: Please be more specific and show a portion of the dict; use fake data if you must. Next, show which how that dict regulates which tests to skip. We need specific details in order to help you.

Comment: @HaiVu I updated the description. Idk if this help. I didn't see any need for these details as the formatting of the dict is irrelevant

Comment: No, your update does not help. I am sorry. I need to see something specific, so make up fake dict if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

For now this way I ended up implementing it:
Create a marker for each feature and made a list which contains a dataclass that will say:

- Which marker is used for the requirement
- Which variants is allowed to execute the feature
- Function that allows me to check the specific configurations in the dict i talked about and if they are within it, allow the test to run the feature.

This actually works pretty well. Only thing I also had to add is support for switching between skipping and running test if variant or configuration within the feature requirement is acceptable for the target under test.

It is pretty easy to implement:

```
# some_file.py
from _pytest import Item

def skip_marker_features(item: Item, feature_requirements: list):
    for marker_data in feature_requirements:
    marker = item.get_closest_marker(marker_data.marker_name)
    if marker is None:  # Marker is none if not found
      continue
    # Handling of condiction
```

conftest.py

```
# conftest.py
feature_requirements = [my_feature_requirement_defined_somewhere]
def pytest_runtest_setup(item: Item):
    skip_marker_features(item, feature_requirements)
```